# SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() not working in Live App

Tags: ios, swift, skstorereviewcontroller

This is my code for Requesting Review :

```
        if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
        }
        else{
            print("Review is not available with in the app")
        }
```

In Development Mode it is working properly & I am able to get PopUp like this:
But In Live app downloaded from appstore, App isnot showing this ratings Popup and nothing happens if user taps out on Ratings Button.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview):

> Although you should call this method when it makes sense in the user experience flow of your app, the actual display of a rating/review request view is governed by App Store policy. Because this method may or may not present an alert, **it's not appropriate to call it in response to a button tap or other user action**.

(Highlight mine)

If you have a Ratings Button like you said in your question, you should not expect it to show the prompt.

The prompt will only show up if:

1. The user hasn't disabled Review Prompts in Settings.
2. The prompt has been shown to the user 3 times or less in a year.

If you *must* request a review upon user interaction, you must direct your users to the App Store page of your app instead, using code like this (taken from [Requesting App Store Reviews Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/requesting_app_store_reviews)):

```
@IBAction func requestReviewManually() {
    // Note: Replace the XXXXXXXXXX below with the App Store ID for your app
    // You can find the App Store ID in your app's product URL
    guard let writeReviewURL = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXXX?action=write-review")
    else { fatalError("Expected a valid URL") }
    UIApplication.shared.open(writeReviewURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what "not appropriate" means in the documentation. I don't have a "Ratings" button, I just want to show the alert after the user interacts with the app. How can Apple know the difference...